# Unbinding Window.grab_mouse

Tags: python, kivy

There is an example of how to bind and unbind files drag&drop from system into Kivy app.
(Perhaps this can be done better, but now it is important that it works)

There are 2 buttons, the left one (roughly speaking) enables files dropping, and the right one - turns this function off.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'bind dropfile'
        on_press: app.bind_dropfile()

    Button:
        text: 'unbind dropfile'
        on_press: app.unbind_dropfile()

'''


class DropFileApp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def manage_dropfile(self, window, fn):
        print('do something')

    def bind_dropfile(self):
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.manage_dropfile)
        print ('bound!')

    def unbind_dropfile(self):
        Window.unbind(on_dropfile=self.manage_dropfile)
        print ('unbound!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropFileApp().run()
```

There is another similar example.
The app also has two buttons.
I expect that when clicking on the left button, the mouse will become limited to the app window area (will not be able to exit it), and when I click on the right button, this function will be disabled.
But only the left button works.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'bind grab_mouse'
        on_press: app.bind_grab_mouse()

    Button:
        text: 'unbind grab_mouse'
        on_press: app.unbind_grab_mouse()

'''

class DropFileApp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def manage_grab_mouse(self, instance):
        print('do something')
        Window.grab_mouse()

    def bind_grab_mouse(self):
        Window.bind(on_cursor_leave=self.manage_grab_mouse)
        print ('bound!')

    def unbind_grab_mouse(self):
        Window.unbind(on_cursor_leave=self.manage_grab_mouse)
        print ('unbound!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropFileApp().run()
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deactivating the connection between the on_cursor_leave event and the manage_grab_mouse function, but you are not disabling the grab_mouse functionality. What you have to do is call grab_mouse() in bind_grab_mouse() function and ungrab_mouse() in ungrab_mouse() function, it is not necessary to create the function manage_grab_mouse.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'bind grab_mouse'
        on_press: app.bind_grab_mouse()

    Button:
        text: 'unbind grab_mouse'
        on_press: app.unbind_grab_mouse()

'''

class DropFileApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def bind_grab_mouse(self):
        Window.grab_mouse()

    def unbind_grab_mouse(self):
        Window.ungrab_mouse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropFileApp().run()
```

Comment: ha, it turns out there is an ungrab_mouse()!